# Is there a more elegant way of doing this? (Cannot be more descriptive.)

Tags: java

I have three non-static classes representing musical composition. These are Score, Part and Note class.

Score contains instance variable `ArrayList<Part>` representing multiple instrument parts of a score, and Part contains instance variable `ArrayList<Note>` representing a note sequence.

```
public class Score {

   private ArrayList<Part> parts;
   private int resolution;

   public Score(int resolution) {
      parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
      this.resolution = resolution;
   }

   public void addPart(Part part) {
      parts.add(part);
   }

   public ArrayList<Part> getParts() {
      return parts;
   }

   public int getResolution() {
      return resolution;
   }
}

public class Part {

   private ArrayList<Note> notes;

   public Part() {
      notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
   }

   public void addNote(Note note) {
      notes.add(note);
   }

   public ArrayList<Note> getNotes() {
      return notes;
   }
}

public class Note() {
   private long startStamp;
   private long endStamp;
   private int resolution;

   public Note(long startStamp, long endStamp, int resolution) {
      this.startStamp = startStamp;
      this.endStamp = endStamp;
      this resolution = resolution;
   }

   public double getDuration() {
      int duration = (double) (getEndStamp() - getStartStamp()) / resolution;
      return duration;
   }
}
```

Duration of each note is calculated using a score resolution. Resolution of a particular Score instance is passed through Note construtor each time note is instantiated. Note is then added to `ArrayList<Note> notes` of a corresponding Part instance, and part is added to `ArrayList<Part> parts` of a Score instance.

My solution of using `int resolution` as a Note constructor parameter doesn't seem elegant, since there are many notes belonging to the same score, i.e. resolution is attribute of a score rather than attribute of a note.

Is there a way to get resolution by referencing  a corresponding Score object from inside Note class, instead of passing resolution through constructor of a Note class, or perhaps some other solution?

Comment: Why not pass the `Score` object itself to the `Note` objects through the constructor?

Comment: Could you give more insights how you use these classes? One notation - the getters for collection fields are usually bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the resolution pertains to the Score (based on your design), not to the note - why not change the method signature of Note#getDuration to calculate the duration at a specific resolution:

```
public double getDuration(int resolution) {
  double duration = (double) (getEndStamp() - getStartStamp()) / resolution;
  return duration;
```

}

The same note can now be added to different scores, with different resolutions.

Or even better, why don't you simply return:

```
public long getDuration() {
  return getEndStamp() - getStartStamp();
```

}

and let the calling code deal with whatever conversion it needs to do?

Comment: Thanks you. That's more elegant way. If feel silly now, how that didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Either you couple them tightly as hell by passing the Score to the Note constructor or you just create a function: getDuration(Node n) in Score itself. That way only Score will know about the resolution, which seems more correct. (Assuming resolution is really a property of Score. I'm dumb to music in general :( )

Edit:

you could surely be more descriptive, with this title for example: *Yes, Beethoven was dumb, but what if he would've been a java programmer as well?* :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do need the duration to be calculated?  I personally try to avoid putting any type of logic in my domain objects, and would have a service calculate the duration of a note outside of all three objects, where you could reference the score and the note.  Perhaps instead of having a startStamp and an endStamp property of note you could have startStamp and duration attributes and calculate the duration when creating the note object.

```
public class Note() {
   private long startStamp;
   private long duration;

   public Note(long startStamp, long duration) {
      this.startStamp = startStamp;
      this.duration = duration;
   }

   public double getDuration() {
      return duration;
   }
}
```